# Java Action Listener Change Object From Source

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I want to change the icon on a button based on what i clicked. The issue is i have an array and it is shuffled so i need a way of changing the icon based on what one of my 30 buttons i clicked.

For example something like this

```
if (source == "dos")
{

change my icon on what button i clicked to this (icon)


}
```

Comment: for a start, assuming that source is a string the correct syntax would be `if (source.equals ("dos"))`.  I think you need to post more code than this, and explain what problems you are having.

Answer (score 1):

> i need a way of changing the icon based on what one of my 30 buttons i clicked.

You get the button that was clicked from the `ActionEvent` of your `ActionListener`:

```
JButton button = (JButton)event.getSource();
button.setIcon(...);
```